# How to communicate between two docker containers (mssql and .net core app) got Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-container, .net-core-2.0

I have a `.net core 2.0` project which uses **mssql server**. I have Created a `docker image` and container for my `.net core 2.0` and running on `9090:9090`. I created it like below.

```
docker container run --name mytestapp --publish 9090:9090 --detach my_.netapp_image_name
```

and below is my connection string in .net core 2.0 app.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=mydatabase;UserId=SA;Password=mydbpassword"
```

**before** this, I created a container for `mssql server` with below,

```
docker container run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>' \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
   -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

- my .net core app has seeds for database. each time it gives me an error says

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught) --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection
>   refused 127.0.0.1:1433) --->
>   System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException:
>   Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433

**NOTE**: this works fine when I run my .net app via IDE(visual studio) and use db as docker mssql container. I ran these two containers separately. then I tried to run using `docker-compose`, but didn't work.

**What am I doing wrong here. hope your help with this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers each have their own network namespace by default. Compose will place all containers on a shared network and set an alias in DNS for the service name. So to connect between containers, all you need to do is point to your service name instead of the 127.0.0.1 (assuming mysql is your service name):

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=mysql;Database=mydatabase;UserId=SA;Password=mydbpassword"
```

This is more portable and handles containers scaling/updating better than to attaching containers to the same network namespace.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get `SocketException: Connection refused`

Comment: @ThomasEyde make sure your application isn't connecting before the DB has finished starting, or use a retry loop.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is the docker sandboxing. For each container that you run you can think of as different virtual environment that has its own host name, IP address and network. While using `-p` only forwards port form that internal network to host. So while you are running from VS you can point to your db using `localhost (127.0.0.1:1433)` just because you have exposed that port to host and your application is starting on host directly. When it is runing inside its own container `localhost` no longer refers to host but rather to that docker environment. To fix this you can run both containers in the same network (`--network` argument on run) and refer from one to another by host name (`--name` argument on run).

```
docker container run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>' \
-p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
-d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest \
--name sql_server

docker container run \
--name mytestapp 
--publish 9090:9090 
--detach my_.netapp_image_name 
--network container:sql_server
```

and in your settings refer to your database as `sql_server`.
To make this process less painful you can research `docker-compose`.