# How to fix error: "Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server"?

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-6.0

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server docker container and migrate the database from the code.

But I get the following error:

> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

My connection string:

```
"CatalogDbConnectionString": "Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=CatalogDb;User Id=sa;Password=Passw@rd"
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
catalogdb:
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - /var/opt/mssql
```

Program:

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CatalogDBContext>();
    var env = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    var settings = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CatalogSettings>>();
    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CatalogDBSeedData>>();

    context.Database.Migrate();

    new CatalogDBSeedData().SeedAsync(context, env, settings, logger).Wait();
}
```

Comment: this should work: 
Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=CatalogDb;User ID=sa;Password=Passw@rd;

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/connect-via-an-ip-address/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/creating-a-valid-connection-string-using-tcp-ip?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @SubodhWasankar I have tried , thank you, but problem still exist)

Comment: Is the program running in a container in the same `docker-compose.yml` file (in which case, [How to communicate between two docker containers (mssql and .net core app) got Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817995/how-to-communicate-between-two-docker-containers-mssql-and-net-core-app-got-c)) or somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, the same docker-compose.yml file. I will check , thank you!

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server is running? DId you run `docker logs <container name>`? I suspect SQL Server is failing to start because `Passw@rd` can't possibly meet complexity requirements.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you. It is running. I have changed password only for example, I don't want to show my favorite combination)) 
I have changed 127.0.0.1,1433 to name of my service and it's working now.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze! It's working because of you!)

Comment: As to why `127.0.0.1,1433` works on the Docker host but doesn't work when the code is executing inside a container... each container is essentially its own little Linux virtual machine and from a networking perspective `127.0.0.1` is the container's own loopback address. To communicate with other containers you reference their container names specified in the compose file (Docker provides DNS services within each composition network). To consume services exposed on the Docker host itself you'd reference `host.docker.internal`.